# Why my compiler (VS2017) choose for 'CALL-JMP' to reach a subroutine instead of just 'CALL'?

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("hello word!\n");
    return;
}
```

Assembly code:

```
push    offset aHelloWord ; "hello word!\n"
call    sub_41104B
add     esp, 4
```

Now, I expect **sub_41104B** will lead directly to printf, but thats not the case:

```
sub_41104B proc near
jmp     sub_411870
sub_41104B endp
```

And finally, in sub_411870, the printf function starts. Can someone explain why the compiler didn't use just directly `call sub_411870`?

Comment: Let me guess, you're not building with optimizations enabled? If you do the result will probably be very different. You can use [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org) to easily see the differences next to each other.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I tried all different kinds of Optimization modes in VS like 'Optimizations (Favor Speed) (/Ox)' and 'Maximum Optimization (Favor Size) (/O1)'. Am i still missing something?

Comment: In the case of VS2015, debug builds will use a set of jumps to functions, but release builds, at least with static library, won't have the jumps.

Comment: Incremental linking will do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, I expect sub_41104B will lead directly to printf ...

... or directly to `puts()`.

> ... but thats not the case

Did you disassemble the object file or the final EXE file?

If you disassembled the EXE file, it is probable that the function you called is implemented in the LIB file as function "renaming" another one:

```
int puts(const char *text) // this is sub_41104B
{
    return __x_puts(text); // __x_puts is sub_411870
}
```

You see this very often when calling a function in a DLL file. However, in the case of DLL files the `jmp` instruction is an indirect jump (`jmp dword ptr [411870]`), not a direct one.